# Unable to import from Keras preprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras/Tensorflow version 2.15.0, and I suspect versioning is relevant to my problem. I'm able to use classes from the [image_preprocessing module](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.15.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py) by importing Keras. What I'm unable to do is use standalone functions from that module or figure out a way to import them.

I can solve the function problem by copying/pasting the function I need of course, but I don't think that's best practice.

Even when I tried that anyway, I ran into another problem: I'm unable to import any of the other modules. The [preprocessing_utils module](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.15.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/preprocessing_utils.py) is the one I had trouble with. The image_preprocessing  module imports it like this:

```
from keras.layers.preprocessing import preprocessing_utils as utils
```

This returns a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.preprocessing' error when I try it. I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I'm able to access the classes in image_preprocessing just by importing Keras, so I have the functions and modules that they rely on installed somewhere. I just can't figure out how to access them in my code.

Comment: Do not import from internal modules, only from the public API.

Comment: Kindly check the Tensorflow 2.15.0 might not be compatible with the specific version of keras what your using and check the availability of the submodule make sure that the submodule keras.layers.preprocessing is available in the version of keras what your using.